# Why does this virtual method return true?

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, virtual

While taking a tutorial on polymorphism in C++, I some code that seems to be acting strangely on the call to a non-overriden virtual method. Here are the classes:

```
// classes.cpp

namespace Classes
{
    class C
    {
    public:
        virtual bool has_eyesight()
        {
            return false;
        }
    } c;

    class See : public C
    {
    public:
        bool has_eyesight() override
        {
            return true;
        }
    } si;
}
```

And here is the main method:

```
// file.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "classes.cpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using Classes::C;
using Classes::See;

int main()
{
    See& si = Classes::si;

    cout << si.has_eyesight() << endl;

    C& c = si;

    cout << c.has_eyesight() << endl;

    c = Classes::c;

    cout << c.has_eyesight() << endl;
}
```

This code will print `1 1 1` (true true true) when run; shouldn't `c.has_eyesight()` return false if it references a C and not a See?

(Forgive me if this sounds naive, I just started learning about C++.)

Comment: c= Classes::c; is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @tp1 Then what does it do? Can you explain it in an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through what you're doing here.

```
C& c = si;
```

`c` is now a reference to `Classes::si`, which is an instance of `See`. So its vtable points to that of `See`, and `has_eyesight()` will return true.

The main difference between a reference and a pointer is that you can't modify its target - `c` will now ALWAYS point to `Classes::si`, no matter what you do. Meaning...

```
c = Classes::c;
```

This will not change the reference to `Classes::c`. You cannot modify a reference. Instead, it calls the assignment operator on c, so now you're copying `Classes::c` over `Classes::si`. Unless you overload `operator=`, this will do a member-by-member copy. It will not modify the vtable, so `has_eyesight()` will continue to return true.

If you do want to make it point to something else, you will have to use a pointer:

```
See* si = &Classes::si;
cout << si->has_eyesight() << endl;
C* c = si;
cout << c->has_eyesight() << endl;
c = &Classes::c;
cout << c->has_eyesight() << endl;
```

Try this.

Comment: Well that's kind of unexpected. Doesn't this imply that you should always make the operator= virtual in polymorphic classes?

Comment: @WorldSEnder it's not obvious why you find this unexpected, [but you are free to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Ah, so I see: the copy assignment overwrites the fields of the `See` corresponding to the fields of the `C` with the fields of `c`, but it basically doesn't touch the methods. Strange stuff; I wonder why they didn't throw some kind of type conversion / runtime error instead of letting this happen.

Comment: Obviously it's valid to assign one `C` to another since they're the same type. With inheritance there's an "is-a" relationship. A `See` is also a legitimate `C`. So that goes back to my first sentence: it's valid to assign one `C` to another.

Comment: Moreover, the assigned to object could be in an unexpected state thereafter: fields from the derived class won't (obviously) get assigned to, meaning part of the object is still in the state before the assignment (slicing). This here is actually an example for a leak in the type system.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
c = Classes::c;
```

is not reassigning the reference. Reassigning the reference is impossible in c++. Instead it does assignment for the underlying value.

Comment: Same for what I said with @RSahu: what does "assignment for the underlying value" exactly mean?

Answer (score 1):

For the second one:

```
C& c = si;
```

`c` is accessed polymorphically, so only the dynamic type count. The dynamic type of `c` is `See`, therefore it selects `See::has_eyesight`.

For the third one:

```
    c = Classes::c;
```

it's not rebinding the reference, it's copy assigning `Classes::c` into `c` itself. References cannot be rebound.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
c = Classes::c;
```

Don't change `c` to reference `Classes::c`. Instead, that line is equivalent to:

```
Classes::si = Classes::c;
```

That doesn't change the virtual table of `si`. Hence, you continue to execute `Classes::See::has_eyesight()` when you use

```
cout << c.has_eyesight() << endl;
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a runtime error, then, if you are trying to assign a base class to a derived class? And if that's true, then why doesn't `Classes::si` become a `C` and return false when `has_eyesight()` is called?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to assign a base class object to a derived class object. When you do that, only the base class portion of the object is affected. The object still continues to be an instance of the derived class, and consequently, the virtual table still corresponds to the derived class.